# How to define a sub-module in Python?

Tags: python, module

Python has a module named "os". It also has some other module named "os.path" which is categorized under the "os".

I can use "os.path" methods even if only import the "os" module.

```
import os

print(os.path.join("sdfs","x"))
```

I wonder how can I define a sub-module like this?

Comment: Inside your module define `__init__.py` inside every directory you want converted to a submodule.

Comment: `os.py` is a file module, but `path` only needs to be a variable within that file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the `__init__.py` 'magic' of the `os` module - it imports its submodule `path` to its namespace, essentially giving you a way to access the latter even if you only import `os`.

```
os
|- path
   |- __init.__.py    # 2
|- __init__.py        # 1
```

The first `__init__.py` (#1) essentially has `import .path` so whenever you import just `os`, it imports `path` in its namespace, and therefore you can access it as `os.path`.

(NOTE: This is not exactly the case with the `os` module, but that's how to essentially achieve it)

Answer (score 2):

Use this structure:

```
/ Package
├── __init__.py
├── file.py
│
├─┐ subpackage
│ ├── __init__.py
│ └── file.py
│
└─┐ subpackage2
  ├── __init__.py
  └── file.py
```

Note each subpackage has its own `__init__.py` file. This will make `Package.subpackage` behave like `os.path`, importation speaking (considering you do not import `.subpackage` under the main `__init__` file of `Package`).

Comment: I couldn't understand. So how my package structure should be? Is  "/Package" name of the "os"?

Comment: @amone `package` is the name of your module (or in that kind of module, better called `package`)